# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to custom data class

Tags: java, android, firebase, hashmap, google-cloud-firestore

I upload my data class object to Firestore, it uploads fine, when I try to download it from another activity the `java.lang.ClassCastException` occurs.
I need the object of Cart class in AddToCart.java to be saved in the Firestore (Success) and get it back in Cart.java (Failure). PLEASE HELP!!!!!

Here is the how I am putting data into the Firestore:

```
 private void updateFirestore() {

    Map cartList = new HashMap<String,CartModel>();

    //I put data into the map

    FirebaseFirestore firestoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firestoreRef.collection(colloctionKeyTitle)
                  .document(currentSelectedModel.getUserId()).set(cartList)
```

Here, the map with one key value is uploaded to firestore:
[image: Firestore image]

NOW, here is the code to get this map back.

```
 FirebaseFirestore firestoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    Task<DocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshot = firestoreRef.collection(COLLECTION_ID).document(userId).get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    cartList = task.getResult().getData();
                    if (cartList != null) {
                        if (!cartList.isEmpty()) {
                            for (String key : cartList.keySet()) {
                                Object object = cartList.get(key);// In object variable I see my data when debug, but app crashes on next line.
                                Constant.listCartItems.add((CartModel) object); //this is the line where error occur.
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is my CartModel.java (Data class)

```
public class CartModel {
private String productTitle,productPrice, featuredImagePath, quantity;

public CartModel(String productTitle, String productPrice, String featuredImagePath,String quantity) {
    this.productTitle = productTitle;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.quantity=quantity;
    this.featuredImagePath = featuredImagePath;
}

public CartModel(String productTitle, String productPrice, String featuredImagePath) {
    this.productTitle = productTitle;
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
    this.featuredImagePath = featuredImagePath;
}

public CartModel() {

}


public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public String getProductTitle() {
    return productTitle;
}

public void setProductTitle(String productTitle) {
    this.productTitle = productTitle;
}

public String getProductPrice() {
    return productPrice;
}

public void setProductPrice(String productPrice) {
    this.productPrice = productPrice;
}

public String getFeaturedImagePath() {
    return featuredImagePath;
}

public void setFeaturedImagePath(String featuredImagePath) {
    this.featuredImagePath = featuredImagePath;
}
```

}

[image: Debug image]

Comment: What type of object gives `cartList.get(key)`?

Comment: Please add the content of your `CartModel` class and please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: added the data class

Comment: @AlexMamo kindly see this.

Comment: @AlexMamo Kindly see this

Comment: One more question. Inside `carItem 0` you want to hold a single or multiple items? This is what you have wanted in the first place, to have those fields under `carItem 0`?

Comment: I have to maintain a cart for specific user so yes against one document Id there will be many CartModel object so yes when you try to get then from firestore than there will be many cartItem, Yes that what I wanted, wait @AlexMamo I will show you.

Comment: Ok, give me an example.

Comment: @AlexMamo see now...……..

Comment: I have attached the debug screen screenshot..... and updated the firestore screenshot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188627/discussion-between-abdul-rahman-shamair-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now in your database structure, that you hold more than one object of type `CartModel` inside that document. To solve this, get the data as a `Map` like in the following line of code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
```

Iterate through the `map` and get all `CartModel` objects from it. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to solve your issue :

## Solution one

cast your Object to the correct one :

```
Object object = (MyObject) cartList.get(key);
                 ^^^^^^^^
```

## Solution two

You have to set the Key and Value type :

```
Map<Key, Value> cartList = new HashMap<String,CartModel>(); 
    ^^^   ^^^^
```

Comment: 1> It is  redundant cast

Comment: 2> I don't control the cartList type, its coming from the server

Comment: Map<String,Object> are the parameters from which the values are coming to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I think issue in the Constant object. There is a mismatch between Constant.listCartItems and the object you put into the map.

Comment: Error occur when I try to cast object to CartModel class.

Answer (score 1):

For Firestore just do document.toObject(Pojo.class)

wolah !